# cuda - directx 12 texture2D (in 1D array) interop

Tags: cuda, directx-12

I'm trying to update in cuda a texture used in directx12. I may miss something but I have no tip about it.

1. there is an "all the time black" area in the top right area of the image.
2. only when I have R G B having the same value for all pixels, I get the expected result (modulo the first problem), if not I have unexpected artefacts, as if the array was not having the expected structure.

What do I miss ?

Here is the creation of the texture:

```
{
    TextureWidth = m_width;
    TextureHeight = m_height;
    auto nPixels = TextureWidth * TextureHeight * 3;
    auto pixelBufferSize = sizeof(float)* nPixels;

    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC textureDesc{};
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
    textureDesc.Width = TextureWidth;
    textureDesc.Height = TextureHeight;
    textureDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;
    textureDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    textureDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

    ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource(&CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT), D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED,
        &textureDesc, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_textureBuffer)));
    NAME_D3D12_OBJECT(m_textureBuffer);

    // Describe and create a SRV for the texture.
    {
        D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc{};
        srvDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
        srvDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
        srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
        m_device->CreateShaderResourceView(m_textureBuffer.Get(), &srvDesc, m_srvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
        NAME_D3D12_OBJECT(m_srvHeap);
    }

    // Share m_textureBuffer with cuda
    {
        HANDLE sharedHandle{};
        WindowsSecurityAttributes windowsSecurityAttributes{};
        LPCWSTR name{};
        ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateSharedHandle(m_textureBuffer.Get(), &windowsSecurityAttributes, GENERIC_ALL, name, &sharedHandle));

        D3D12_RESOURCE_ALLOCATION_INFO d3d12ResourceAllocationInfo;
        d3d12ResourceAllocationInfo = m_device->GetResourceAllocationInfo(m_nodeMask, 1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(pixelBufferSize));
        auto actualSize = d3d12ResourceAllocationInfo.SizeInBytes;

        cudaExternalMemoryHandleDesc externalMemoryHandleDesc;
        memset(&externalMemoryHandleDesc, 0, sizeof(externalMemoryHandleDesc));
        externalMemoryHandleDesc.type = cudaExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Resource;
        externalMemoryHandleDesc.handle.win32.handle = sharedHandle;
        externalMemoryHandleDesc.size = actualSize;
        externalMemoryHandleDesc.flags = cudaExternalMemoryDedicated;

        checkCudaErrors(cudaImportExternalMemory(&m_externalMemory, &externalMemoryHandleDesc));

        cudaExternalMemoryBufferDesc externalMemoryBufferDesc;
        memset(&externalMemoryBufferDesc, 0, sizeof(externalMemoryBufferDesc));
        externalMemoryBufferDesc.offset = 0;
        externalMemoryBufferDesc.size = pixelBufferSize;
        externalMemoryBufferDesc.flags = 0;

        checkCudaErrors(cudaExternalMemoryGetMappedBuffer(&m_cudaDevVertptr, m_externalMemory, &externalMemoryBufferDesc));
        RunKernel(TextureWidth, TextureHeight, (float*)m_cudaDevVertptr, m_streamToRun, 1.0f);
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(m_streamToRun));
    }
}
```

And here the cuda code for updating this texture:

```
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return a % b != 0 ? a / b + 1 : a / b; }

__global__ void TextureKernel(float *pixels, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, float time)
{
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (y < height && x < width)
    {
        auto pos = (y * width + x) * 3;
        auto sint = __sinf(time) * 0.1f + 0.10f;
        auto sintAlt = (x / 32) % 2 == 0 ? 1.0f : sint;
        pixels[pos + 0] = sintAlt; //RED
        pixels[pos + 1] = 0; // (x + y) % 2 == 0 ? 1.0f : __sinf(time) * 0.25f + 0.75f; //GREEN
        pixels[pos + 2] = 0; // (x + y) % 2 == 0 ? 1.0f : 0.0f;                       //BLUE
        //pixels[pos + 0] = __sinf(time + 0.) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
        //pixels[pos + 1] = __sinf(time * 0.09) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
        //pixels[pos + 2] = __sinf(time + 2) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
    }
}

void RunKernel(size_t meshWidth, size_t meshHeight, float *texture_dev, cudaStream_t streamToRun, float animTime)
{
    //dim3 block(16, 16, 1);
    //dim3 grid(meshWidth / 16, meshHeight / 16, 1);
    auto unit = 32;
    dim3 threads(unit, unit);
    dim3 grid(iDivUp(meshWidth, unit), iDivUp(meshHeight, unit));
    TextureKernel <<<grid, threads, 0, streamToRun >>>(texture_dev, meshWidth, meshHeight, animTime);
    getLastCudaError("TextureKernel execution failed.\n");
}
```

And an extract of the resulting image I get with this code:

[image: result image]

And the full repo if needed:

https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update

---

**EDIT**
Two problems occur here.

The first is the format of texture: `R32G32B32float`, but the RTV (?) is expecting actually `R32G32B32A32float`. Matching everything at `R32G32B32A32float` can solve the weird colors arrays. The other way is to match the RTV to a `R32G32B32float` texture, but I don't see how.

The second problem is to work with `cudaExternalMemoryGetMappedBuffer` instead of `cudaExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray`; however how to use it with the texture described by `D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC textureDesc{};` as well as a 1D cuda array `float*` is no clear yet.

I tried with the following code (for a 1D mipmap array), without success (`cudaErrorInvalidValue`).

```
auto textureSurface = TextureWidth * TextureHeight;
auto texturePixels = textureSurface * TextureChannels;
cudaExternalMemoryMipmappedArrayDesc cuTexDesc{};
cuTexDesc.numLevels = 1;
cuTexDesc.extent = make_cudaExtent(texturePixels, 0, 0);
cuTexDesc.formatDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
auto result = cudaMallocMipmappedArray(&cuMipArray[0], &cuTexDesc.formatDesc, cuTexDesc.extent, cuTexDesc.numLevels);
```

Comment: I might want to use `cudaExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray` instead https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXTRES__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__EXTRES__INTEROP_1g091a4383a816eb7127aa5c7a7c32cef7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right thing to do is to import the texture as external memory, then as mipmap array, then use this array to create a cuda surface, and then modify this surface in the cuda kernel.

The import and mapping is done this way:

```
cudaExternalMemoryMipmappedArrayDesc cuExtmemMipDesc{};
cuExtmemMipDesc.extent = make_cudaExtent(texDesc.Width, texDesc.Height, 0);
cuExtmemMipDesc.formatDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float4>();
cuExtmemMipDesc.numLevels = 1;
cuExtmemMipDesc.flags = cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore;

cudaMipmappedArray_t cuMipArray{};
CheckCudaErrors(cudaExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray(&cuMipArray, m_externalMemory, &cuExtmemMipDesc));

cudaArray_t cuArray{};
CheckCudaErrors(cudaGetMipmappedArrayLevel(&cuArray, cuMipArray, 0));

cudaResourceDesc cuResDesc{};
cuResDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
cuResDesc.res.array.array = cuArray;
checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&cuSurface, &cuResDesc));
// where cudaSurfaceObject_t cuSurface{};
```

the cuda part looks like this:

```
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return a % b != 0 ? a / b + 1 : a / b; }

__global__ void UpdateSurface(cudaSurfaceObject_t surf, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, float time)
{
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (y >= height | x >= width) return;

    auto xVar = (float)x / (float)width;
    auto yVar = (float)y / (float)height;
    auto cost = __cosf(time) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
    auto costx = __cosf(time) * 0.5f + xVar;
    auto costy = __cosf(time) * 0.5f + yVar;
    auto costxx = (__cosf(time) * 0.5f + 0.5f) * width;
    auto costyy = (__cosf(time) * 0.5f + 0.5f) * height;
    auto costxMany = __cosf(y * time) * 0.5f + yVar;
    auto costyMany = __cosf((float)x/100 * time) * 0.5f + xVar;
    auto margin = 1;

    float4 pixel{};
    if (y == 0) // paint the first row
        pixel = make_float4(costyMany * 0.3, costyMany * 1, costyMany * 0.4, 1);
    else if (y == height - 1) // paint the last row
        pixel = make_float4(costyMany * 0.6, costyMany * 0.7, costyMany * 1, 1);
    else if (x % 5 == 0) // paint a column of 1 pixel wide every 5 pixels
    {
        if (x > width / 2) // a certain color for the right half
            pixel = make_float4(0.1, 0.5, costx * 1, 1);
        else // another color for the left half
            pixel = make_float4(costx * 1, 0.1, 0.2, 1);
    }
    else if (x > width - margin - 1 | x <= margin) // first and last columns
        pixel = make_float4(costxMany, costxMany * 0.9, costxMany * 0.6, 1);
    else // all the rest of the texture
        pixel = make_float4(costx * 0.3, costx * 0.4, costx * 0.6, 1);
    surf2Dwrite(pixel, surf, x * 16, y);
}

void RunKernel(size_t textureW, size_t textureH, cudaSurfaceObject_t surfaceObject, cudaStream_t streamToRun, float animTime)
{
    auto unit = 10;
    dim3 threads(unit, unit);
    dim3 grid(iDivUp(textureW, unit), iDivUp(textureH, unit));
    UpdateSurface <<<grid, threads, 0, streamToRun >>> (surfaceObject, textureW, textureH, animTime);
    getLastCudaError("UpdateSurface execution failed.\n");
}
```

I updated the git repo to reflect those changes (https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update)

Answer (score 2):

You assume that a 2D texture image with three channels of type float will have a simple row-wise linear memory layout. As demonstrated by your result, this is generally not true.

Textures are optimized for spatially-coherent access. Their memory layout is designed to keep things that are close in n-dimensional texture space close in memory. This cannot be achieved for anything with more than one dimension by a simple row-major memory layout. The exact memory layout of a particular texture image is generally not something you can assume to know or rely upon. It will depend on the GPU you're using (typically, the data will be stored in some way that employs things like tiling or [Morton order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), with padding in places to keep stuff aligned).

As you noticed yourself, what you want to do is use [`cudaExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXTRES__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__EXTRES__INTEROP_1g091a4383a816eb7127aa5c7a7c32cef7) to map a CUDA array (arrays are the CUDA-analogon to texture images) to your external data coming from D3D12. The format of this CUDA array will have to match the format of the texture created in D3D12. You should then be able to use the texture or surface functions of the CUDA runtime API to access the texture image represented by this CUDA array…

Comment: That's a good explanation of one aspect of the problem, but it can't be a solution (texture interop D3D12-cuda).

Comment: @Soleil I'm not sure what you mean by that. You cannot interpret the data of a 2D texture image as a linear buffer. I mean, you can, but you cannot expect the results to be meaningful for the reasons laid out above. If you want texture interop, you have to interop with texture image data as a texture image, not as a linear buffer…

Comment: I had to interpret the D3D texture in the end as a 2D cuda surface (and through mipmap array, and 2D array, cf. my answer)